# make selection color range, skin tone, fuzziness > 0 100% transparent or 100% opaque

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have an action in Photoshop cs6 (win7/64) which does the following:

1. select color range, skin tones, fuzziness=56
2. refine edge, radius 42 pixels, smoothness=61, feather=0, shift edge-15, smart radius, decontaminate colors=67% and save to new layer
3. duplicate layer 3 time
4. merge down 3 times  << to try to solidify the selection
5. save as png
6. close

It shows just the skin areas and some hair if blond, but the edges and parts of the inside are semi-transparent. I want either 100% opaque or 100% transparent and nothing in between. If I made 256 copies and merged them all, that would surely do it. With the 4 duplicates of the selected layer, turning them invisible one at a time, the transparency on the edges noticeably increases.

I turned feathering=0 and tried to move the edge inward 15 pixels.

I want the result to be as though I went in with the eraser tool and deleted every non-skin pixel with a razor edge.

And, the deleted areas can either be white or transparent (or black)?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: To the GRUMP with the -1 vote: searching for the title here gives exactly 1 hit, this one.

Comment: I down voted.. ...read what you've posted. ... **What *exactly* is the question???** Searching has *nothing* to do with how unclear this question is. I see you've used the question mark... is *that* why you feel this is a question?? Because reading it... I can't find an *actual* question anywhere.

Comment: In addition, you've clearly visited Photography.SE why aren't you asking this there?

Comment: Question: Skin tone selection has semi-transparent areas. How to make entire image either 100% opaque or 100% clear

Comment: From ORIGINAL QUESTION..."parts of the inside are semi-transparent. I want either 100% opaque or 100% transparent and nothing in between."    Is this like Jeopardy??      To Clarify, how does one delete, clear, destroy, make transparent or otherwise get rid of areas resulting from a select -> color_range which are semi-transparent?

Comment: Perhaps you might consider clicking the [edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/53658/edit) link and rephrasing to **clarify** things in a manner others may find easier to interpret.

Comment: Brian, I have read your post a couple of times now but I still don't fully understand. If you attach some images to illustrate what you mean, I think that would help a lot. You clearly know what you want to achieve, but as it appears to be a mildly complex operation, unfortunately (and frustratingly for you), you've not expressed it very concisely. The question looks well structured, it's just that you are not getting you point across. Your comments (especially the second one) seem to be clearer. As Scott suggests, take a step back and rephrase it. I haven't downvoted you, btw. :-)

Comment: Greenonline, The BIG IDEA was to Cut out skin tones from a photograph and have a binary selection; SKIN or NOT-SKIN. The question was How to take a selection with various levels of transparency and make everything either fully selected or fully non-selected.    How is it possible to clarify the concept of SELECTED or NOT-SELECTED?    How would one Disambiguate this sentence: "I want either 100% opaque or 100% transparent and nothing in between."   This depends on knowing how "REFINE EDGE" works and outputs to a "NEW LAYER".   The ANSWER is BELOW...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I started with some random pic I found online and I used the same settings that you did in step 1

[image: guy]

I think you may want to play with these two settings in your Refine Edge process, until you get something closer to what you want:

[image: refine]

It's also not a good idea to have such a confrontational attitude with people you want to help you - that's just my two cents.

Comment: JM,  I cranked both the contrast and smoothing to 100 and got better results. But, when you are moving the edge in on a face, you always have some color contrast and therefore a smooth edge is difficult (if not impossible). I found that placing the initial mask on a solid black background and then moving it in again with refine edge finds no color resistance and so gives smooth edge. And another gotcha, if you have semi-transparent stuff and dup^3/merge_down^3, the opacified areas are average from all the layers. BAD. Must mask pristine layer!